# Unity , восстановление шкалы

Tags: c#, unity3d

Здравствуйте : хотел спросить как можно подкрутить пополнение шкалы , при подборе предмета ? У меня нормально не вышло , но вот рабочий код самой шкалы

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class LightScript : MonoBehaviour
{


    public int fuel = 300;
    public Slider slider;
    private float time;
    void Start()
    {
        slider.value = 1f;
    }


    void Update()
    {
       // fuel -= Time.deltaTime * 0.1f ; 
        slider.value = fuel;
        time += 1 * Time.deltaTime;
        if (time >= 1) {
            fuel -= 1;
            time = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Почитайте про `FixedUpdate()`, вдруг пригодится.

Comment: и еще про короутины. Там можно пополнять, например, раз на секунду.

Answer (score 0):

Всё очень просто:) :

```
public Slider slider;
private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision collision){
if(collision.gameObject.tag=="item"){
slayder.valuer=?????
}
} //Убери 2D, если у тебя в 3D
```